# JMeter JMS Publisher IBM MQ Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: jmeter, jms, ibm-mq

Getting Error for JMS IBM MQ

> Response message: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/disthub2/impl/client/SessionConfig

Followed the steps from here: http://leakfromjavaheap.blogspot.com/2014/07/jmeter-and-websphere-mq-series.html?_sm_au_=iVV5P5vR626sDt7V

I don't see any error in jmeter log file.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking into wrong place, the class you're missing lives in [`com.ibm.mq.allclient`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.mq/com.ibm.mq.allclient) jar.

1. Download `com.ibm.mq.allclient` jar along with dependencies
2. Put the libraries somewhere to [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
3. Restart JMeter to pick the libraries up

Also depending on your MQ server configuration you might need to do some coding exercise using [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) as [JMeter JMS components](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-jms-topic-test-plan.html) most likely won't be suitable for your scenario. See [IBM MQ testing with JMeter - Learn How](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/ibm-mq-testing-with-jmeter-learn-how) article for more details and example configuration/code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add ibm jms client jars and dependencies in jmeter /lib folder?

If not, do it and restart